# Lists windows of width 1

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to generate list windows of width1:

```
% All of the width1 windows of the list:

window1(L1, [I], L3, R) :-
    append(L1,[I],L1I),
    append(L1I,L3,R).
```

```
?- window1(L1, L2, L3, [a,b,c,d,e]).
```

Nicely generates:

```
% All of the width1 list windows:
L1 L1  L3        R
[],[a],[b,c,d,e],[a,b,c,d,e]
[a],[b],[c,d,e],[a,b,c,d,e]
[a,b],[c],[d,e],[a,b,c,d,e]
[a,b,c],[d],[e],[a,b,c,d,e]
[a,b,c,d],[e],[],[a,b,c,d,e]
```

... and then explodes. Can you explain why it doesn't terminate (and how to fix)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- why it doesn't terminate.

When all solutions have been exhausted, the system backtracks to the first append, which obliges with a solution:

```
window1(L1, [I], L3, R) :-
    append(L1,[I],L1I), % solution 6: append([_,_,_,_,_],[I],[_,_,_,_,_,I])
    append(L1I,L3,R).
```

That solution fails in the next append, as R has too few items for it to be suitable, then backtracking brings another solution, which also fails, etc.

- how to solve it.

You could limit the calls to append:

```
window1(L1, [I], L3, R) :-
    % [I|L3] means list with head I, tail L3
    append(L1,[I|L3],R).
```

Depending on how you use the clause, you may still get infinitely many solutions, but you won't in your original case, and the call will exit.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your first goal, `append(L1, [I], L1I)` when used with L1 and I arguments uninstantiated. This will generate infinite solutions with L1 having 0 to infinite unisntantiated items and L1I as L1 concatenated with I. 
The second goal unifies R and when R is a proper list it will yield your intented solutions, but then on backtracking it the first goal will continue to generate lists.

You may directly use this:

```
window1(L1, [Item], L3, R):-
  append(L1, [Item|L3], R).
```